# In Liquid Templates is there a syntax for writing the input to the output as is?

Tags: json, liquid

I would like to use a liquid template to map data but for one case I need the template to just pass out exactly the json I'm sending in. What is the syntax for that? Something like {{ content }}

Comment: The data in JSON format you want to insert, are generated at each deployment of your environment, are they dynamically generated by scripting languages or do they have to be inserted manually into the content?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. My content is coming from another application in a particular json schema. I want to just pass it along to my Logic App unchanged - but my process is setup to go through liquid templates maps so I'd like the map to just literally write out what it receives.